# PHP Remove neighboring close and open script tags

Tags: php, html, regex, replace

Say I have

```
<script>alert("hello");</script><script>alert("world");</script>
```

How could I remove the `</script><script>` keeping in mind that there may or may not be a space in between (`</script> <script>`) and I would not want to do this if either of the script tags has the source attribute (`src`) set.

This should work with as many script tags as possible, so if there were three in a row that follow the same requirements, it would be turned into one big script tag.

Comment: Have you tried something ?

Comment: I got as far as removing the script tag with or without the space, but I'm not sure where to begin even by checking if either have the `src` set

Comment: Sounds like you're parsing HTML with regex, Tony will be coming soon ?

Comment: ^ Then show your work and effort in your question

Comment: Do you want to strip tags? :)

Comment: @Cristik, you're question just made me think of a possible solution. I'll post what I've come up with in a moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You state that there may be "a" space. If that is the case, you have two situations: `</script><script>` and `</script> <script>`. You can easily replace both with a space:

```
$html = str_replace('</script><script>',' ',$html);
$html = str_replace('</script> <script>',' ',$html);
```

But, what if there is a lot of whitespace? Tabs, newlines, etc... all add up to whitespace. You can preg_replace (which is NOT parsing HTML with regex - it is just replacing a clearly defined string).

```
$html = preg_replace('~</script>\s*<script>~',' ',$html);
```

NOTE: If the second <script> is actually <script src='blahblahblah'>, it won't match using either str_replace or preg_replace. That is a non-issue.

Comment: As pointed out in my comments I should have added this in my question, but I have gotten this far, but what I don't know what to do is do this when only both don't have the `src` set. And yes, I am only searching _a_ space.

Comment: In that case, I cheat. First, I change <script src='blahblah'></script> to something else like <script src='blahblah'></NOTASCRIPT>. Then, I do my replacements. Then, I change NOTASCRIPT back to script. Much easier than mucking around with all the possible things you will come up with.

Comment: Cheating was a good way to do it. But I cheated a little harder than you suggested. Since script tags with `src` set don't have contents and the ones without do, I came up with this piece of code that did exactly that.

`$Render = str_replace('></script>', '></NOTASCRIPT>', $Render);
$Render = preg_replace('~</script>\s*<script>~', ' ', $Render);
$Render = str_replace('></NOTASCRIPT>', '></script>', $Render);`

Answer (score 1):

use

```
 $pattern="/<script[^s>]*>\s*<\/script>/isU";
 $html=preg_replace($pattern,"",$html);
```

pattern look for script tag that have no src attribute basically we are finding if it has s inside or not and remove that script opening and closing tag seperated by zero or more space

Answer (score 0):

@kainaw's answer is correct, but i have here one sophisticated version, where you can allow just some tags, and will return space, that was present between them.

```
function remove_same_openclosed_tags($matches){
  $allowed_tags = ['em', 'u', 'span', 'strong', 'script'];
  if(in_array($matches[1], $allowed_tags) && $matches[1] == $matches[3] ) {
    return $matches[2];
  }
  return $matches[0];
}
$content = preg_replace_callback("/<\/([a-zA-Z]+?)>(\s*)<([a-zA-Z]+?)>/is", 'remove_same_openclosed_tags' , $content);
```